# Insert and delete in a transaction always block the rows?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have this table:

```
TableAB
{
    IDA;
    IDB;
}
```

And I want to ensure that always I have the pair (ID1, ID2) and (ID2, ID1). So I am trying to use this to scripts:

To insert:

```
begin tran
insert into tablaAB (IDTablaA, IDTablaB) VALUES(1,2);
insert into tablaAB (IDTablaA, IDTablaB) VALUES(2,1);
commit
```

To delete:

```
begin tran
delete tablaAB where IDTablaA = 1 and IDTablaB = 2
delete tablaAB where IDTablaA = 2 and IDTablaB = 1;
commit
```

I am using two instance of Microsoft Management Studio, to run both queries, and in most of the cases, it works, I get the two rows or any of them. But sometimes, I get only one of them.

The steps are:

- run the query to delete (1,2).
- run the query to add (1,2).

In most of the cases, it is block until the transaction to delete both rows finishes, but in some case it can pass to the next line, to insert the second row. If this happens, then I don't have a coherence data.

But I don't know if it is because I make some mistakes in the test or in same rare cases the first query is not blocked as I expect.

Really in all cases the first insert should be block if the first delete is done?

The table is empty. So it seems that the row is blocked when I try to delete and it doesn't allow to insert the row, but I don't know if really can be some rare situations in which the row is not blocked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
But I don't know if it is because I make some mistakes in the test or in same rare cases the first query is not blocked as I expect.

Really in all cases the first insert should be block if the first delete is done?
```

It seems you are running using the READ COMMITTED isolation level. In this case, no lock is held by the DELETE session when no rows qualify so the INSERT session can proceed to insert rows. This becomes a race condition where you may end up with zero, one, or two rows. Consider this sequence that results in one row:

```
--session 1:
begin tran;
delete TableAB where IDTablaA = 1 and IDTablaB = 2;
--no row deleted, no lock held

--session 2:
begin tran
insert into TableAB (IDTablaA, IDTablaB) VALUES(1,2);
--row inserted, lock held
insert into TableAB (IDTablaA, IDTablaB) VALUES(2,1);
--row inserted, lock held
commit;
-- inserts committed and locks released

--session 1:
delete TableAB where IDTablaA = 2 and IDTablaB = 1;
--row deleted, lock held
commit;
--deleted committed, lock released
```

If you instead use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, the `DELETE` statement will hold a lock (table lock in this case due to no indexes) and block the insert session. A less restrictive key range lock will be held with an index on the column used to locate rows to be deleted.

Note that `SERIALIZABLE` is it is more prone to deadlocks than less restrictive isolation levels.